# Schema design for Hotel Room Rate

Tags: sql, oop, schema

I'm designing a hotel reservation system. The rooms are categorized into different types like, single king, double bed, suite etc. For each room type, there can be different rates depending on day of the week. For example, single king would cost 100 on Sunday to Thursday and on Friday, Saturday, it'll be 150.

What is the optimal schema design to store Room, Room Type, Room Rate for different days of week in a table? Only way, I can think of is creating a record for every single day for every room type. Like,

```
Room Type1, Monday, 100
Room Type1, Tuesday, 100
Room Type1, Friday, 150
Room Type2, Monday, 180
```

and so on.

Is there any better design than this?

Comment: To make your current approach even more general, you could store the date when a given room type assumes a _new_ rate.  Then, any date _after_ that date would have the same rate, until it gets overwritten.  But a bigger problem with your design might happen if some rooms don't neatly fit into a certain type.  What would happen then?

Comment: yeah, that's true. in addition, I'll also have a problem when I've to change the rates for special dates like new years eve or any other holiday. hence, i'm here looking for some other design approach

Comment: yor record should have date_from, date_to, day_of_week_from, day_of_week_to(days 0-6 or 1-7)

Comment: From experience booking hotels, the pricing seems to be a black art. I would spend a lot of time working through all the possible use cases before I put together my design. If its a simple course question with your defined requirements then something like the above comments are fine. Of course you also have RoomType as a separate table.

Comment: @TomC I'm keeping that in mind. I'm making my design that can be extended based on different rate cases in the future. It sure is challenging. For example, the future features need differential rates based on the room availability as well. More and more I think, I should separate out the rate logic from reservation system and keep it as a separate microservice.

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. And I think you are right with making it more than a simple lookup. Availability is a huge factor - rates can double or triple if there is a major sporting event or concert in town for example. Or if you book a month in advance rather than a day. or you stay over a weekend, etc etc. I think a service is a good idea, it may well become the most complex part of your system.